# Copying in Excel while picking up multiple rows that are feeding input into the copied Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am a starting VBA enthusiast and I would like some help on the below formula as I have no idea how to make sure the formula applies to all rows in the book. As you can see, I have started copying the actual code, but as I have to do this for up to 100 rows this will be too manually.

Thanks

```
Sub Charts()
    ' Charts Macro
    ' Run charts
    Range("D7").Value = Range("D11")
    Range("E7:G7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D7").Value = Range("D12")
    Range("E7:G7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D7").Value = Range("D13")
    Range("E7:G7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D7").Value = Range("D14")
    Range("E7:G7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Charts()
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 11 To 14 '<~~ Change 14 to whatever row you want to go to
            .Range("D7").Value = .Range("D" & i).Value

            .Range("E7:G7").Copy
            .Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```